# Angular 2 passing data between parent and child components inside router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have two calls to be made in parent component:

1. Load dropdown values from server
2. Based on selected dropdown value, load data from the service.

Now I need to pass this data on loading of child component as well as when dropdown changes.

Note, the data passed is a complex JSON object. Is there any other way than using (?.) in HTML in order to prevent errors?

Comment: Give us some code , where is the child component located ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared service. Set the data there on dropdown change and access the same in child using ngOnInit method of interface OnInit.